# Results returned from requests.post()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm working on a small python script that should return a list of data from an icinga server - I have it working with curl, but I need it in Python. This is the curl version:

```
$ curl -k -s -u karl:marx -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET' -X POST 'https://zenoss.hpc.ic.ac.uk:5665/v1/objects/services' -d '{ "filter": "service.state==state && match(pattern,service.name)", "filter_vars": { "state": 2, "pattern": "*checkmem" } }' | jq '.results[].attrs | [.host_name, .name, .last_check_result.output] | @csv' | sed -e 's/.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk//g' -e 's/\\n/\n/g' -e 's/\"\\\"//g' -e 's/\\\",\\\"/\n/g' -e 'a ------'
```

The python script that I believe implements this, is:

```
$ cat icinga_report
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import json
import sys

if len(sys.argv)==3:
    state=int(sys.argv[1])
    service=sys.argv[2]
else:
    print 'Usage: icinga_report state service'
    sys.exit()

hdr={
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'X-HTTP-Method-Override':'GET'
}
aut=(
    'karl',
    'marx'
)
url='https://zenoss.hpc.imperial.ac.uk:5665/v1/objects/services'
dat={
    'filter':'service.state==state && match(pattern,service.name)',
    'filter_vars':{
        'state':int('%d'%state),
        'pattern':'*%s'%service
    }
}

res=requests.post(
    url,
    headers=hdr,
    auth=aut,
    data=json.dumps(dat)
)

print res
```

However, the output from running the script:

```
$ ./icinga_report 2 checkmem
<Response [200]>
```

And in fact, it looks like it is the same if I use any other, valid URL - I just get the response code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests.post` returns a `requests.Response` object. You should output its `content` attribute instead if you want to see the content of response:

```
print res.content
```